# Reducing null rows in mysql query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

How to reduce those null rows? I was trying using `DISTINCT` for id`s. `SUM()` is casting varchars to numbers. As a result i need only one `products_id` with all attributes.

I already have this as a query (I've done some pivoting and filtering from bigger db):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  tab1.products_id,
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 2 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'cpu_producer',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 3 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'cpu_clock',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 4 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'cpu_family',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 5 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'cpu_description',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 8 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'gpu_producer',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 9 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'screen_diagonal',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 10 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'system',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 11 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'screen_resolution',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 12 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'gpu_memory',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 13 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'screen_coating',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 14 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'screen_touch',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 21 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'color',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 22 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'type',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 23 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'cpu_threads',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 24 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'ram_type',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 25 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'ram',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 26 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'drive_type',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 27 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'drive_size',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 28 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'gpu_name'
  FROM
(Select
    products_to_products_extra_fields.products_id,
    products_to_products_extra_fields.products_extra_fields_id,
    products_to_products_extra_fields.products_extra_fields_value,
    products_extra_fields.products_extra_fields_name
From
    products_extra_fields Inner Join
    products_to_products_extra_fields On products_to_products_extra_fields.products_extra_fields_id =
            products_extra_fields.products_extra_fields_id  
ORDER BY `products_to_products_extra_fields`.`products_id` ASC)tab1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do, by doing an outer Select
wITH A GROUP BY AND max;

The aggregation function depends on the data and whether there are only 1 or more possibilities , so that you must use GROUP_CONCAT ti get them all

```
SELECT
    products_id,
    MAX(cpu_producer)  cpu_producer,
    MAX(cpu_clock) cpu_clock
 #   ...
    FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT 
  tab1.products_id,
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 2 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'cpu_producer',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 3 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'cpu_clock',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 4 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'cpu_family',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 5 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'cpu_description',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 8 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'gpu_producer',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 9 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'screen_diagonal',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 10 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'system',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 11 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'screen_resolution',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 12 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'gpu_memory',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 13 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'screen_coating',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 14 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'screen_touch',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 21 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'color',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 22 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'type',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 23 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'cpu_threads',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 24 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'ram_type',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 25 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'ram',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 26 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'drive_type',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 27 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'drive_size',
  (CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 28 THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value END) AS 'gpu_name'
  FROM
(Select
    products_to_products_extra_fields.products_id,
    products_to_products_extra_fields.products_extra_fields_id,
    products_to_products_extra_fields.products_extra_fields_value,
    products_extra_fields.products_extra_fields_name
From
    products_extra_fields Inner Join
    products_to_products_extra_fields On products_to_products_extra_fields.products_extra_fields_id =
            products_extra_fields.products_extra_fields_id  
)tab1 ) t1
GROUP BY products_id
ORDER BY products_id ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

- Remove `DISTINCT`
- Add `GROUP BY tab1.products_id`
- Wrap each separate `(CASE WHEN ... END)` into MAX(), like:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN tab1.products_extra_fields_id = 2 
         THEN tab1.products_extra_fields_value 
         END) AS 'cpu_producer',
```